# Attribution of quote "The apparent duck becomes an obvious rabbit"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

The quote

> The apparent duck becomes an obvious rabbit

refers to a paradigm shift. I've only seen [one paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/philosophy.pdf) including it, and the author uses it as if it is common. Is it used elsewhere, or with a different comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limited as Google is as a tool for lexical research, the fact that Googling the phrase fails to turn up anything beyond this question suggests it's unique to the author. I don't think they've used it as though it's common, though; it's simply a reference to a relatively well-known visual paradigm shift.

[image: duck-rabbit]

Answer (score 3):

At least in philosophy, the duck-rabbit illusion was first made famous by Wittgenstein in his "Philosophical Investigations": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations

Comment: also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Jastrow


the feminist Gilligan talks about it and it is discussed in relation to the philosophy of Merleau-Ponty's